# IntelliJ not marking files with errors in Play Framework app

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using IntelliJ to develop a Play app and one thing that bugs me is that files with errors are not highlighted in the Project window (see attached image).

Since there is an error in the `Application.scala` I would expect the file to be marked with red lines in the Project window on the left.

I've checked with a plain scala project and it's working there so I guess my setup with play isn't correct.

In this example I've simply created a blank new play app and imported it into IntelliJ by selecting the build.sbt in the import wizard of IntelliJ.

[image]

Comment: Tip: use `play idea` command to create IntelliJ settings and then `Open project` instead importing `build.sbt` (don't think anyway it's related to bug)

Comment: IntelliJ: 13.0.2
Play: 2.2.1
Scala: 2.10.2
Java: 1.7.0_40

Comment: `Opening` the project did not help unfortunately

Comment: Hm, I just can confirm ...